# Как с помощью jQuery вырезать текст и вставить в другой input

Tags: jquery

Помогите пожалуйста собрать функцию на jQuery, в которой по клику кнопки из textarea будет выделен и перемещен в другой input тег iframe.
Например:

```
<textarea  id="block1">Текст из которого нужно достать этот <iframe src="http://domain.com" widht="100" height="100"></iframe> и переместить его в другой input
</textarea>
<input id="this" value="">
<button id="butt" type="button">Переместить</button>
```

Comment: iframe имеет одинаковый источник?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/ https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/DOMParser